# Running customized (non-BPMN) process definitions with Activiti

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn

We are evaluating Activiti as a process engine to replace our existing home grown work flow engine. We are quite impressed by the capabilities of Activiti especially related to multi tenancy and REST WS.

However, one of the biggest challenge (and probably blocker) to adopt Activiti would be - How we can run or migrate our existing work flow definitions.

As I mentioned earlier, our work flow solution is a home grown one and doesn't adheres to BPMN specifications. There are thousands of templates out there. We can't simply ask our customers to redefine their templates using Activiti. These definitions are stored in proprietary XML format.

Looking at the level of customization in the templates, it would be very difficult to migrate these definitions to BPMN format.

So, does Activiti provides any hooks to run such custom templates. Alternatively, please share your thoughts about migrating the templates from proprietary format to BPMN format.

I suppose such scenario would be common and other people would have faced the same.

I know I am being very vague with this query but at this stage I don't have specific problems that I can discuss.

Answer (score 0):

One option is implement your own proprietary XML parser and parser handlers. Look at *org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParse* and *org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.handler.AbstractBpmnParseHandler* and its descendants.

We did it and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks fersmi. By proprietary XML Parser and handler, I understand that they were used to parse your custom templates. Please suggest if I my understanding is correct. My main confusion stems from mapping of the custom constructs to the BPMN constructs. Did you faced this situation and how were you able to handle it.

Comment: The XML parser reads each xml elements and put it to appropriate handler (AbstractBpmnParseHandler). The Handler converts an element to activiti node. For example StartEventParseHandler adds StartEvent to process definition. That is a way, how to make process definition for deploying to database from own XML format.